# Updating a database using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, newsletter

I'm trying to create a newsletter function, when a user inputs their name and email into a form, the PHP issues a query to the database to put their answers in the table. I already checked the names of everything and they all seem to be in check, but for some reason "why please no" keeps showing up.

This is my code, it worked once before but I'm not sure what happened.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("connecting");                             
mysql_select_db("ejb")or die("database");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$query = "INSERT INTO 'newsletter'('name', 'email') VALUES ('$name', '$email')";
if(mysql_query($query)) {
    echo "updated";
    }
else{
    echo "why please no";
    }
?>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: get rid of the `'` around newsletter. and stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. also, escape any value you insert into a db, or better yet, use prepared statements.

Comment: Please stop using the `mysql_*` functions; they are deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. Also, you are wide open to SQL injection and will get hacked if you use this code. Finally, turn on error reporting while testing your code. You have multiple, obvious typos, which would have been easy to correct.

Comment: looks like you are starting out on using mysql php.  A suggestion for best practice is  to use PDO library for db functions.   mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `newsletter`(name, email) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."')";
```

Try using this query, i Think the problem is from `'newsletter'('name', 'email')` instead of `newsletter(name, email)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO  your_database.your_table (columnname1, columnname2) VALUES ('$var1','$var2')";
```

or in your case:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO  ejb.newsletter (name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')";
```

Comment: Mind Explain your code ?